# Laptop doesn't recognize phone connecion

Tags: samsung, usb

My Samsung a20e is not recognized by laptop.

When connected,phone is charging but nothing changes in computer. No notification, nothing in device manager. Phone is in mtp mode and I installed all drivers.

Comment: Try a different USB cable. May be the cable you use is defect or supports only charging.

Comment: I have done it and my laptop died. Thats fault of bad usb but is there any possibility i can fix it and motherboard is not gone??